# Python for loop through array creating JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have code to create a json object file and makes it into pretty print in a new file. Found here:

```
# Creates a storage file for the
with open('placeInfo.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(api.trends_place(id=location_array[1]), outfile)

with open('placeInfo.json', 'r') as handle:
    parsed = json.load(handle)
    prettyFile = json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    pfFile = json.loads(prettyFile) #use for indexing
    print prettyFile

x = 'number1'
f = open(x + 'newFile.json', 'w')
f.write(prettyFile)
```

What I want to do is loop through an array (0-17 elements) and use `id=location_array[x]` to index each location within the array.

```
x = 0
while x < len(location_array):
    with open('placeInfo.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(api.trends_place(id=location_array[x]), outfile)
    with open('placeInfo.json', 'r') as handle:
        parsed = json.load(handle)
        pretty_file = json.dumps(parsed, indent = 4, sort_keys = True)
        print pretty_file
        f = open(x + 'newFile.json', 'w')
        f.write(pretty_file)
    x += 1
```

The first code block returns a valid new json file but this while loop does not even recognize one json file. Where am I going wrong here? Also is there any simplification of this code that can be recommended?

Comment: Why would you write a file and then immediately reread it? If you want to have your output prettified, you can do that in the first place by passing `indent` and `sort_keys` on the *first* dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not use while loop for this usage.

The good way to do :

```
for x, value in enumerate(location_array):
    # Then you can access to the value you want with
    print value
    # Instead of
    print location_array[x]

    # And you still can access to the index
    print x
```

Also, you should open all your files with the `with` syntax. In your example you have forgetten to close the last file you open (xnewFile.json). It's bad. With the `with` syntax you will not have to worry about that.

So I think this should work :

```
for x, location in enumerate(location_array):
    with open(x + 'newFile.json', 'w') as outfile:
        parsed = api.trends_place(id=location)
        json.dumps(parsed, outfile, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Comment: The array is holding all int values so I cannot open x + 'newFile.json'